# Use of setInterval on javaScript

Tags: javascript

As always, I would appreciate very much if somebody out there could help me a little bit with this code.

I have the following lines of code:

```
var count = 0;
var limit = 2000;
function liveCount(){
    var increment = count + 10;
    count = increment;
    if(count <= limit){
        document.getElementById('showCount').textContent=count;
    }else{
        clearInterval();
    }
}
var counter = setInterval('liveCount()', 10);
```

What this code does is simulate a counter from 0 to X as a chronometer would do. 
It works perfect when I use it stand-alone, it starts counting and updates the count in 10 miliseconds intervals until it reaches the limit and then it stops.
So far so good.
My problem is that when I nest this code inside another function, which is the one that will provide the value for the "count and limit" variables, I get an error saying that the "liveCount()" is not defined, refering to the parameter of the "setInterval()".

I have tried everything I can think of and I cant get it to work.
Any ideas what am I missing or doing wrong?

Thank you all.

Comment: Please give an example of 'nesting the code inside a function'

Comment: you aren't passing the handle to `clearInterval`.

Comment: The nesting code is a simple function that takes an retrieves an integer, and that is what I use as the value for the limit variable.
NOthing else to it really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've written it, `liveCount` must be a property of the global `window` object. Putting this code inside a function defines `liveCount` as local to that function, which means that `window.liveCount` does not exist.

**Don't** pass `setInterval` code to execute; instead, **give it a reference** to the function, like this (notice that there are no quotes):

```
var counter = setInterval(liveCount, 10);
```

Full example:

```
function someOtherFunc(limit) {
    var count = 0;
    function liveCount() {
        var increment = count + 10;
        count = increment;
        if (count <= limit) {
            document.getElementById('showCount').textContent = count;
        } else{
            clearInterval();
        }
    }
    var counter = setInterval(liveCount, 10);
}
```

You probably also want to return `counter` (or something like that), but you don't show enough code to be sure.

Comment: Thanks you very much, it worked now. I figured there was some sort of issue with scope, but it escaped me. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for...

```
function liveCount(count, limit){
    var increment = count + 10;
    count = increment;
    if(count <= limit){
        document.getElementById('showCount').textContent=count;
    }else{
        clearInterval(counter);
    }
}

function wrapper() {
    // calculate count and limit
    count = 0;
    limit = 2000;
    liveCount(count, limit);
}

var counter = setInterval(wrapper, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put what your invoking inside a closure.

```
var counter = setInterval(function() {
    liveCount();   
}, 10);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MattLo/HATmY/